# Conditions for a projection of algebraic set to be algebraic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projection

A linear projection of an algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is not always algebraic, for instance, the projection of $\{xy=1\}$ on the $x$ axis yields $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$.

My question is - are there conditions for a projection to be algebraic? Say if all of the fibers have the same dimension? Something more general, or in terms of how $X$ behaves when compared to its projective closure?

Thank you!

Comment: This is discussed in Cox, Little, and O'Shea's *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*, chapter 3, section 2. They give a decomposition of the vanishing set of an elimination ideal in terms of the projection and another set given explicitly in terms of equations for the original variety. I believe this leads to the definition of constructible sets.